# Drush 8.0.3 Failed to get available update data and simplexml_load_file warning

Tags: drush

Please, can someone offer help with this error:

> drush dl simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity [warning] "" Project.php:74 Failed to get available update data from [error] https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x Could not download requested project(s). [error]

I am using FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE-p9 with PHP 5.6.18. My current Drupal sites work OK, but they need updating.

```
Drush installed OK 
drush status PHP configuration : /usr/local/etc/php.ini 
PHP OS : FreeBSD Drush script : /usr/local/bin/drush 
Drush version : 8.0.3 
Drush temp directory : /tmp 
Drush configuration : 
Drush alias files :
```

I can run commands like:

```
drush pmi
```

but I can't seem to connect and download anything from Drupal. 
Your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the problem read https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/55183/#post-312401